# What is the best way to express the future in this case

Tags: future-tense

Which is the best?

> 1. Once you've paid, we will take an appointment with your sister.
> 2. Once you've paid, we are taking an appointment with your sister.
> 3. Once you've paid, we are going to take an appointment with your sister.

I think the first one and third are better because in sentence 2 we could understand that the present progressive expresses the present which is not the case.

Comment: If you're going to contract ***you've***, it would usually be more natural to also contract ***we will*** to ***we'll***. Note that you ***make*** (not ***take***) an appointment. Other than that, your first version is natural, the second is syntactic garbage, and the third is "credible, but unlikely".

Comment: what do you mean by syntactic garbage?

Comment: You should _always_ wait before accepting an answer. Please read our **[Not so fast!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)** meta post. The first answer may not be the best, or even correct.

Comment: Is this an establishment talking to a client? I've never heard "take an appointment with". Usually, clients "make appointments with a service provider". If the business is taking action, I'd say "schedule an appointment for your sister".

Comment: Option one is correct; not the second and the third. The clauses starting ....we are starting, or ....we are going to start are expressions generally of actions scheduled to happen in the future.  When I say, I am leaving for London, it means it is scheduled, whereas, I shall leave....is dependent on what precedes (as one could see in the examaple). By syntactic garbage, @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, possibly meant that the sentences have scope to syntactically improve. :)

Comment: @RamPillai: OP's example #3 here is syntactically perfectly valid, and could occur quite naturally in at least *some* contexts. There can sometimes be a nuance of difference between *I will [verb]* and *I'm going to [verb]*, but I don't think that would normally be relevant in the context of a hypothetical / future scenario of the general form ***If / once / when** X happens, Y **will / is going to** happen.*

Comment: Another Alternative would be, 'Once you've paid, we schedule an appointment with your sister'. You could use present simple to refer to a future arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

All three versions are grammatically valid..

> Once you've paid, we will make an appointment with your sister.

There is no rule about the consistency in making contractions within a statement, or series of statements. I myself most likely would have structured the statement in this way.

> Once you've paid, we are making an appointment with your sister.

This statement conveys a kind of authority, and is perfectly acceptable.

> Once you've paid, we are going to make an appointment with your sister.

Basically the same as the other two, but a bit more wordy (and a bit less authoritative).

Comment: Sentence 2 is not remotely idiomatic in English! The present progressive is not used to express the future. This usage would only be heard in Indian "English".

Comment: ..So you're saying that "once you get dressed, we are leaving" is incorrect too?? Can you provide some literature that outlines this? Thanks.

Comment: No, _that_ construction is fine. I ought to have written: _"We would not use the present progressive as in the second example sentence."_ This is worthy of a question, and I encourage you to post it!

Comment: I think the "once" phrase is begging for some kind of explicit marking of the future tense.

Comment: So why  is present progressive  not possible in the second example?

Comment: Present progressive in (2) is quite acceptable to me.  Present progressive is used in situations that refer to future time.